# GWT cells selection

Tags: gwt

I wish to make a drag and select application in GWT where I wish to have cell table or grid of say 20*100 columns*rows. I want to add a event such that I can drag something like a rectangle with my mouse and all the cells in that region get selected or I can fire an event for each cell and assign each of them a same ID. The main idea behind the thing is to perform a selection by dragging and then grouping all selected cells as one, something like Excel sheet selection. Can any one help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have once implemented GWT widget allowing to "select" some rectangular region of a table. Basically the idea was to subclass a [Grid](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Grid.html) or [FlexTable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html) and do all the logic in various mouse event handlers (mouse down, mouse up, mouse out, mouse over).

The only minor hack I had to introduce was a method for getting the cell for any mouse event. There is a method [HTMLTable#getCellForEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.html#getCellForEvent%28com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent%29) that works for a click event, but when I looked into implementation of this method, I saw that it could actually work for any event, so I just implemented my own method for getting cell for any mouse event based on mentioned implementation.

Maybe it would be also possible to achieve this using [HTMLTable#getEventTargetCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.html#getEventTargetCell%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Event%29)